# Putting RewriteEngine On in subdir .htaccess file disables rewrites regarding this subdir specified in root .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

I have working rewrite rule in /.htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/uploads/sites/[0-9]+/xxx_uploads/ [NC]
RewriteRule wp-content/uploads/sites/[0-9]+/xxx_uploads/(.*) wp-content/files.php?file=xxx_uploads/$1 [R=302,L]
```

which disallows unauthorized users viewing files in specific directories.

It works as long as there is nothing in /wp-content/uploads/.htaccess

If I put at least `RewriteEngine On` there, the rule from root .htaccess stops working.

It seems there is nothing with inheritance as `RewriteOptions Inherit` doesn't change anything.
The question is: how to make the rule from root .htaccess work with rules in subdirectory .htaccess?

Apache 2.4.38

Comment: _Aside:_ "It works as long as there is nothing in /wp-content/uploads/.htaccess" - Why/how would you have another `.htaccess` in this subdirectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is expected behaviour. mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default. So if you enable (or disable) the rewrite engine in a child config it completely overrides mod_rewrite directives in the parent config.

> It seems there is nothing with inheritance as `RewriteOptions Inherit` doesn't change anything.

It should, however...

`RewriteOptions Inherit` would need to go in the `/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess` file, not in the root `/.htaccess` file. However, mod_rewrite "inheritance" works by virtually copying the directives in-place. So this will not help in this instance since the `RewriteRule` directive as posted will not match when "inherited", ie. when virtually copied to the `/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess` file.

To resolve this, you can enable mod_rewrite inheritance in the parent (root) `.htaccess` file using `RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore` (requires Apache 2.4.8) and modify the rule so that it would work in both the root and child `.htaccess` files (in fact, anywhere).

For example:

```
# /.htaccess

RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/uploads/sites/[0-9]+/xxx_uploads/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule . /wp-content/files.php?file=xxx_uploads/%1 [R=302,L]
```

This rule will now work regardless of where the `.htaccess` file is located (or where it is inherited). Note that `%1` (as opposed to `$1`) is a backreference to the preceding *CondPattern* instead.

Note the slash prefix on the *substitution* string to make it a root-relative URL-path.

However, this may not work if you have other directives in the root `.htaccess` file, as these will also be "inherited".

---

Alternatively, you put your rule(s) in a *server* or *virtualhost* context (not inside a `<Directory>` container) and they will always run before the directives in any child `.htaccess` files.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/uploads/sites/[0-9]+/xxx_uploads/ [NC]
> RewriteRule wp-content/uploads/sites/[0-9]+/xxx_uploads/(.*) wp-content/files.php?file=xxx_uploads/$1 [R=302,L]
> ```

As written, the `RewriteCond` directive is entirely superfluous. (Providing the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is anchored, ie. `^wp-content/....`)